# Replace a second field output with sed or awk

Tags: shell-script

I have a below content in a file where i need to search the pattern "application:" , where "application:" should be there but the next field to it should be changed to "RMAN" , I am trying to do with sed but unable to get it in one go.. any help appreciated

$ cat myjobs

update_job: P_rman_INC1_HCMS2   job_type: CMD

group: DBA

application: RMAN

update_job: P_rman_INC1_HCMPRTL   job_type: CMD

group: DBA

application: Mybox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the example input you gave:

```
sed -e 's/application:.*/application: RMAN/g' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simple output printing

```
sed -e 's/application:.*/application: RMAN/p' filename
```

To modify the file directly

```
sed -i 's/application:.*/application: RMAN/g' filename
```

Also you can modify one by one in case you want to change a specific `application:` line.

```
$ vim myjobs
~
~
~
~
:%s/application: /application: RMAN/gc
```

This will ask you line by line if you want to replace the pattern or not.